# How to use CCPhysicsBody?

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2017, portable-class-library, cocossharp

I want to get into physics with CocosSharp. I was about to use [CCPhysicsBody](https://github.com/mono/CocosSharp/blob/master/src/physics/CCPhysicsBody.cs) in my PCL project, however it's not available in the namespace "CocosSharp".

Checking my NuGet packages (CocosSharp.PCL.Shared), the last package publish date is two years old. Do I miss CCPhysicsBody, because my packages are too old? Why there is no up2date package then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer here: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/308757#Comment_308757

It's still not part of the NuGet, thus I need to compile CocosSharp with the physics flag, by myself.

Comment: thanks for sharing your solution here, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues.